Azure b2c sharing tokens between apps with an IDP login
We use Azure AD B2C for our authentication layer in our applications. We've written a custom policy to allow federation to Azure AD. This all works.
We now have a prospective customer who is using a third-party IDP, which we want to hook into our security system. I know we can do this by creating a user flow and adding an OpenID Connect identity provider to it.
We have done this and it seems to work. However, we don't want to add a different B2C policy to our applications as they are used by multiple customers.
I was hoping that we could provide our customer with a website they could log into using this bespoke B2C user flow, and we could then redirect them to our standard website and avoid them having to log in.
This doesn't seem to work if they log in via the IDP button though.
I tried creating a user flow and added an OpenID Connect IDP to it. This appears on the user flow as a button. If I log in via a local B2C user I can open one of our applications and it automatically logs me in. If I login via the IDP this doesn't work
If I log into the user flow using local B2C users it's fine, so it's not the different B2C policies that's the issue. It must be something in the tokens themselves, or more specifically the one passed back from the IDP.
Can anyone let me know if this is even technically possible, and if it is what I can do to make it work? Are user flows the answer or is the only option the dreaded custom policies.

Please include more details like any code your tried or errors to better understand your requirement
